# Creating nested json object using mysql query

Tags: javascript

I currently have a json file that is hard coded. Here is a snippet:

```
 {
  "name": "Projects",
  "children": [
   {
     "name":"Project_Category(example:MobileApps)", 
     "description":"category",
     "children": [{
     "name":"Sub_category(example:MusicPlayer)",
     "description":"some_description(example:The music app will play music from an android device...)",
         "children":[
             {//child 1 of the MusicPlayer subcategory
             "name": "Actual_project_name(example:JukeBox)",
         "description":"Actual_project_description",
             "children":[
                 {"name":"projectGroupMember1", "email":"groupMember1Email@yahoo.com"},
         {"name":"projectGroupMemeber2", "email":"groupMember2Email@yahoo.com"}
              ]}, 
              { //child 2 of the MusicPlayer subcategory
        "name": "another_project_title",
        "description":"another_project_description",
                "children":[
            {"name":"projectGroupMember1", "email":"groupMember1Email@gmail.com"},
            {"name":"projectGroupMember2", "email":"groupMember2Email@gmail.com"}
                 ]
              }
           ]//end of MusicPlayer's children
    }, //end of MobileApps children
...
```

Having a database where all this data is stored, I have been trying to use php and nested mysql queries to generate this output to a json file which I will use for other tasks (data visual). My goal was to generate this file everytime the web application is opened so I can the have the most up to date version of it from the database. However, I have been having difficulties using nested mysql queries to create this output. So my question is, given the way my json file is structured is this feasible? Is there a better approach I should do instead? Any suggestions would help.

Comment: why do that in nested sql queries? Divide and conquer and build up the json step by step. Not everything needs to be done in one step

Comment: You need to provide more information. What's your database structure like? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

mysql does not generate any nested structure for you. You have to do it by yourself.

There are many frameworks that would do it for you. The question is what server you have.

For example there is cakephp for Php which could give you a very similar structure. Also ASP.NET MVC with code first can do that. There are tons of possiblities.

If you want to do it without any framework, we still need to know, which server you use.